# Find the number of even factors of 126000

Tags: prime-factorization

What is an easy way to solve the problem? I can solve it by trying all possible even numbers, but I don't think it is a smart way.

> Find the number of even factors of 126000.

Comment: prime factorization

Comment: An even factor of 126,000 is a factor of 63,000 multiplied by 2. So you are looking for the number of factors of 63,000.

Comment: Ain't that hard to factorise, given that there are already three trailing zeroes...

Answer (score 3):

An even factor of 126,000 is twice a factor of $63,000=(2^3)(3^2)(5^3)(7^1)$.  Can you find the total number of factors id 63,000 from that prime factorization?  That will count the even factors of $63,000·2=126,000$.

Answer (score 2):

$126000 = 2^4*3^2*5^3*7$

Every and only numbers of the form $2^i3^j5^k7^l$ where $0 \le i \le 4; 0 \le j\le2;0 \le k\le3 ;0\le l\le1$ are factors. To be an even factor $1 \le i \le 4$.

So there a $4$ possible powers of 2, $3$ possible powers of 3 ($0, 1,$ or $2$), $4$ possible powers of 5, and $2$ possible powers of 7.  Thats $4*3*4*2 = 96$ even factors.

===

or to see this clearly:

The only possible factors are: $(1|2|4|8|16)*(1|3|9)*(1|5|25|125)*(1|7)$.  That's $5*3*4*2$ possible factors.

The even factors are: $(2|4|8|16)*(1|3|9)*(1|5|25|125)*(1|7)$.  That's $4*3*4*2$ even factors.

Answer (score 0):

$$
126000 = 2 \cdot 63 \cdot 1000 
= 2\cdot 9 \cdot 7 \cdot 2^3 \cdot 5^3 
= 2^4 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 5^3 \cdot 7
$$
An even divisor has the form
$$
2^{p_1} \cdot 3^{p_2} \cdot 5^{p_3} \cdot 7^{p_4}
$$
with 
$$
p = (p_1, p_2, p_3, p_4) \in 
\{ 1, \dotsc, 4 \} \times 
\{ 0,\dotsc, 2 \} \times
\{ 0,\dotsc, 3 \} \times
\{ 0,\dotsc, 1 \}
$$
so there is at least one factor $2$ in its product.

There are $4 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 \cdot 2 = 96$ different choices for the powers $p$ and the same number of resulting even divisors.